# How Do I align my second Text widget with the circle avatar baseline

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
body: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 50,
                child: Text('Sample'),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Flutter McFlutter',
                  style:
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Experienced App Developer',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

[image]

Comment: Try using the `mainAxisAlignment` property of `Column` widget to achieve this

Comment: No it is not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code hope its useful to you use ListTile() widget for that refer listtile [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html) or set `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end` inside column

```
 ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        radius: 50,
        child: Text(
          'Sample',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      title: Text(
        'Flutter McFlutter',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 30,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        ),
      ),
      subtitle: Text(
        'Experienced App Developer',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Your result screen using ListTile-> [image]

Comment: Thaank you So much for helping me out..This answers my Query perfectly with your crisp and crystal clear answer

Comment: Welcome @KavachDheer if your problem is solved by my answer please upvote and accept it. Thanks

Comment: I am trying to that but it is showing you need 15 reputation to cast a vote :(

Comment: @KavachDheer ok accept my answer just click on correct (tick ) option go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) also

Comment: I have done that.Thank you for providing me the documentation.One thing more I wanted to ask.You can totally decide not to answer.I have just started my development journey and I am learning from the GoogleCodeLabs. Is that the best way to learn or if you could guide from transforming from a beginner to expert like you. Any tips,Suggestion would be helpful :))

Comment: Thanks @KavachDheer **GoogleCodeLabs** is good way , you can learn flutter developement for **Flutter** official documentation [here](https://flutter.dev) , learn **Dart** [here](https://flutter.dev/) and you need to some **packages** or **dependencies**  go [here](https://pub.dev/) and many of flutter course available on You tube also, if any query and help please let me know, Thanks. Glad to help you, Enjoy your ride with **FLUTTER**

Comment: Can you help me Once more . on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69758430/mainaxissize-spaceevenly-not-giving-equal-space-in-the-widget

Comment: just check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69758536/13997210) hope its helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

Set the crossAxisAlignment for the Row to `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end`

Comment: Using this both the text widgets are aligning with the Circle avatar..I want only the second Text widget to align with the circle avatar..Can you help me out ..New to the programming world :))