# MainAxisSize.SpaceEvenly not giving equal space in the widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-layoutbuilder

**This is the Code**

```
body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/website/master/examples/layout/sizing/images/pic1.jpg'),
                    radius: 50,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 30,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Text('Post'),
                        Text('Followers'),
                        Text('Following')
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

Comment: `Expanded(child: Container(child: Row(...` but actually you dont need that `Container` at all and you can just `Expanded(child: Row(...`

Comment: @pskink like always, answering in the comment :) cheers mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code hope its helpful to you,used ListTile widget also refer ListTile [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html), refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69720140/13997210) for same design

```
 ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
          'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/website/master/examples/layout/sizing/images/pic1.jpg',
        ),
        radius: 50,
      ),
      title: Container(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Text('Post'),
            Text('Followers'),
            Text('Following'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Your result screen like-> [image]

Comment: Thank you So much for your crisp clear answer once again :))

Comment: most welcome @KavachDheer glad to help you please upvote my answer, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Container** doesn't take all reaming space (give a background color to the container and see). that's the reason you don't see `MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,`. Use a **Expanded** widget which take all remaining space. then you will see the effect.

> Containers with no children try to be as big as possible unless the incoming constraints are unbounded, in which case they try to be as small as possible. Containers with children size themselves to their children. The width, height, and constraints arguments to the constructor override this.

```
Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/website/master/examples/layout/sizing/images/pic1.jpg'),
                radius: 50,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 30,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Text('Post'),
                    Text('Followers'),
                    Text('Following')
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Thank you So much for your crisp clear answer :))